# Changing AV from Computer Associated to other Forefront?

Tags: anti-virus, microsoft-forefront

Has anybody used Microsoft Forefront?  I have heard good things so far. But if you are a Microsoft hater don't just say its poor quality.  Please support your opinion.  Keeping in mind it is extremely good value if you have a Microsoft agreement.

I currently use Computer Associates which "does not support virtualisation AND does not plan to support ESX 4.0 in the release of r12 which is in Beta".  This is according to their technical support which has confirmed according to their road map.

I just need a centrally managed enterprise antivirus solution that supports clients and servers. No need for mail scanning etc as we already have a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my earlier answer to a s[imilar question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/12516/what-is-the-best-antivirus-for-a-windows-domain-network/12524#12524).  For us, ESET was a bargain, was judicious with system resources, works well on both servers and clients, and had very good central management features at no extra cost.  No mailserver scanning features with the standard Smart Security or NOD32 products (Outlook and Thunderbird plugin is included though) but it sounds like that's not an issue for you.  We've been very happy (and also came from CA, coincidentally).

Comment: Do you run it in a virtual environment. If so what are you running.

Comment: Not in a server capacity - we've had it on a few desktop guests running under VirtualBox, and it ran fine - it doesn't have any issues with bridged networking, which can be a source of problems with some anti-virus and software firewall programs. 

The best way to determine if it will work for you in this setting is to download the free trial and give it a shot - we settled on ESET after running the free trial of both ESET and Symantec for a month or so, and it was invaluable to get the chance to kick the tires and see how each performed before shelling out.

Comment: Did you find the central management good?

Comment: Yes, we installed the free Remote Admin (RA) Server and have been pretty happy with it.  We use it to monitor the deployment across all of our servers and workstations, including remote offices and mobile users.  We're able to centrally monitor alerts and logs, update configurations, and create and view scheduled scans or other jobs.  There's also a remote install/deployment feature, but I haven't tinkered with it.

Comment: How many workstatsions do you have in your enterprise? and users?

Comment: We're under 50 workstations/users so "Enterprise" probably isn't the word -- more the 'S' end of 'SMB'. :-)  But we're spread out, so the ability to centrally manage has been an important feature.