# Is it possible to buy and run Microsoft Forefront Client Security Agent without server?

Tags: untagged

I'm trying to choose a antivirus solution for tiny non-profit organization (5 workstations, no server).

Is it possible to buy licenses and run Microsoft Forefront Client Security Agent on these workstations? [$12/year per device license](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/clientsecurity/en/us/pricing-licensing.aspx) is a good price.

But if I have to purchase Management console for $1000, which reporting features I don't need, and a server, it won't make any sense.

Microsoft Security Essentials would suffice, but it's impossible to buy it for non-personal use - and free license does not allow it.

Comment: Slightly related question here, in case it's got anything you can use http://serverfault.com/questions/123025/anti-virus-malware-solution-for-small-non-profit-network

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/) is [available for small business](http://www.microsoft.com/Presspass/Features/2010/sep10/09-22SecurityEssentials.mspx) use on up to 10 clients since, well, quite recently.

From the current license agreement:

> - Small Business
>
>   - If you operate a       small business, then you may install     and
>       use the software on up to ten
>       (10) devices in your business.
> - Restrictions
>
>   - The software may not be     used on a device running an
>       enterprise version of a Microsoft
>       Windows operating system.
>   - The
>       software may not be used on devices
>       owned by government or academic
>       institutions.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into purchasing your software from [TechSoup](http://home.techsoup.org/)? In my work with non-profits, I've found them to have very competitive prices on Microsoft (and other) software. You do have to go through the hassle of helping them verify your non-profit status, but after that, it's fairly easy to order.

With regards to your specific question, I'm afraid I don't have any experience with MS Forefront.

Comment: TechSoup is fine in US, but for my country (Poland) it's offer is much more limited. I can't get Forefront from this program.