# Best antivirus comparison site

Tags: windows, anti-virus

I am purchasing an anit-virus for a small network ( 10 servers about 15 workstations ), all windows at the moment. I have looked at a few anti-virus comparison sites, but many of them seem rather sketchy.

Which anti-virus comparisons sites are the most trustworthy?

Which do you use?

I want to add that I need this for a small business network, so I need some kind of central management system.

Comment: I use Microsoft Security Essentials - free and seems to hog less resources than any other AV I've used.

Comment: MSE is good for a free/home product, but unfortunately doesn't have any type of centralized management options or other features that even a relatively small network would find useful.

Comment: nedm, you are right, central management is a requirement for me. I use MSE on some personal systems and recommend it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_antivirus_software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't compare any comparison sites for you, but there have been [plenty of discussions](https://serverfault.com/questions/12516/what-is-the-best-antivirus-for-a-windows-domain-network) [on this site](https://serverfault.com/questions/123025/anti-virus-malware-solution-for-small-non-profit-network) about different antivirus products, which I guess is another way of saying '[this one.](http://serverfault.com)'

Answer (score 4):

Hands down:

http://www.av-comparatives.org/

They do a good job of testing many products and have both Retrospective and On-Demand scanning tests.

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm responding to a late thread, but I've had good luck with Symantec Endpoint Protection deployments. At home I use Microsoft Forefront, but mostly because I have a TechNET subscription.

I suppose it would depend on what features you're looking for. Single management point? Outbreak prevention? Symantec also offers a firewall built into the Endpoint Protection package. Fortunatly, one can create a custom install package without the firewall in it.

I manage the Windows firewall via GPO, and have the SEP client deployed both through GPO and WDS.

That, and licenses can be picked up from Newegg.